# running a linux server from home

Tags: linux, php, apache-http-server, vps

Is it possible to run a linux server from home on my personal machine. 
The VPS seems bit expensive at this stage. I dont have a big user base but on a share
hosting my php based script (socialengine) runs very slow.

Regards

Parminder

Comment: yes it is possible.

Comment: Your ISP probably won't like you, as @kobaltz says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.  But there are some caveats:

1. you should get a static IP address from your ISP.  If you don't have one, you'll need to look into a dynamic-DNS provider to keep your web-site online and tied to your DNS entry for it.
2. The problem with at-home servers is the upload bandwidth is typically low.  So if you don't have too many users, you'll be fine.  But if you're web pages are serving a lot of data (eg, images) or if you have a lot of users it'll start causing problems.  It will never "feel" as fast as hosted system in a data-exchange, but most people won't complain.

Comment: Don't forget that a lot of home ISPs will prevent you from having servers. They typically cannot monitor port 80 or 443, but they may shut you down if you have a FTP, SSH, SMTP, POP, etc.